# python regular Expression splitting a string

Tags: python-2.7

I want to split a `sting c='[ 6638.392700] Entered some command E0, 00, 01'`
in to
`['6638.392700','Entered some command E0, 00, 01' ].`

I want to split the number in [data] from the string. How can I achive that?
I tried like this below:

```
re.split(r'([\d*])',c,re.I)
```

BUT it is giving me output like   ..
          `['[ ', '6', '', '6', '', '3', '', '8', '.', '3', '', '9', '', '2', '', '7', '', '0', '', '0', ']` Entered some text `E', '0', ', ', '0', '', '0', ', ', '0', '', '1', '']`

How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: i think just google for basic RE module information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Define the string:

```
>>> c = '[ 6638.392700] Entered some command E0, 00, 01'
```

Split it:

```
>>> c.replace('[','').split(']')
[' 6638.392700', ' Entered some command E0, 00, 01']
```